# Jakarta EE, Maven with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, jakarta-ee

Can these be developed in Visual Studio Code and what are advantages?

I have been using Eclipse but I have seen some videos showing VSC with Jakarta EE and I would like to give it a try so I am looking for others' experiences and maybe a tutorial on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using maven you can write your code anywhere even in a simple text editor so yes you can use it and VSC is just a text editor with some plugins to support languages and their syntax highlighting.

ide is for making things simpler and I think IntelliJ idea is the best for java you can find a list of them for Jakarta EE development [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-choose-an-ide-to-build-a-jakarta-ee-applica).